# Change the key based on the constructor variables values during object initialization in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

even though I am a programmer for couple of years, I still always try to find the best way to do it,

Here is one my challenge and I want to the best way to do it,

```
MutableEventInstance mutableEventInstance = new MutableEventInstance(key, start, stop, value);
```

class definition

```
public class MutableEventInstance {

   private int key;
   private int start;
   private int stop;
   private double value;

   /*'***************************************************************************************
   *   Class members                                         
   ******************************************************************************************/

   public MutableEventInstance(int key, int start, int stop, double value) {
      this.key = key;
      this.start = start;
      this.stop = stop;
      this.value = value;
   }

   /**
    * @return the key
    */
   public int getKey() {
      return key;
   }

   /**
    * @return the start
    */
   public int getStart() {
      return start;
   }

   /**
    * @return the stop
    */
   public int getStop() {
      return stop;
   }

   /**
    * @return the value
    */
   public double getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   /**
    * @param key the key to set
    */
   public void setKey(int key) {
      this.key = key;
   }

   /**
    * @param start the start to set
    */
   public void setStart(int start) {
      this.start = start;
   }

   /**
    * @param stop the stop to set
    */
   public void setStop(int stop) {
      this.stop = stop;
   }

   /**
    * @param value the value to set
    */
   public void setValue(double value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

}
```

the key value will be incremented starting from zero when any of start/stop value differ from the previous values.

I could only guess, store the previous start & stop values and then increment.

Is there any best way to do it ? Please advise.

I need to aggregate the value based on the key in Spark 2.3

Example:
The key value need to be incremented when start/stop has changed. How do I do this ? At the method where initialing of those objects happens ?

```
Key=0, Start = 3, Stop = 7, Value = -10.0
Key=0, Start = 3, Stop = 7, Value = 0.0
Key=0, Start = 3, Stop = 7, Value = 0.0
Key=0, Start = 3, Stop = 7, Value = 3.03
Key=0, Start = 3, Stop = 7, Value = 0.0
Key=0, Start = 3, Stop = 7, Value = 0.0
Key=0, Start = 3, Stop = 7, Value = 2.5

Key=1, Start = 5, Stop = 6, Value = -10.0
Key=1, Start = 5, Stop = 6, Value = 0.0
Key=1, Start = 5, Stop = 6, Value = 0.0
Key=1, Start = 5, Stop = 6, Value = 3.03
Key=1, Start = 5, Stop = 6, Value = 0.0
Key=1, Start = 5, Stop = 6, Value = 0.0
Key=1, Start = 5, Stop = 6, Value = 2.5
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Besides, there is never one "best way" to write a solution. Everything has a trade-off.

Comment: Added an example to clarify what I am looking for

Comment: I still don't understand. What are the types of these things? Integers? Integers are immutable; you can't increment them.

Comment: My advice: stop worrying about whether your solution will be "best". Write something which works and refine it. Post your attempt to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You boosted me....Will implement my own stuff and refine it. Now I have updated the post once again

Comment: Within the `set…` methods, both, the old and new value, are available. So incrementing another int value when the differ, seems a no-brainer. It’s not clear, what your question is.